# How to Add Column in Final Excel file from merged excel files

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I currently have this excel macro below that basically merging all files indicated in the path into one excel file.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\MERGE")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Now, my problem is that, I want to include the file name of each excel file on one column of the final excel file that contains all the data from the merged excel files.

Also is it possible to include formatting in macros? Like the font style/size/bold?

Answer (score 2):

I refactored the code a bit to be able to add the file name to column next to the right-most column for each data file pasted in. I commented my edits with `**`.

*(For your 2nd question. There are numerous resources to see how to adjust cell formatting in VBA on the web. A simple search will yield many results)*

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()

    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim wbMain As Workbook '** just to work directly with this workbook object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim lBeginRow As Long
    lBeginRow = 1 '** start with row 1 at beginning of loop

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\MERGE")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj

        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
        'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
        'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
        'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
        bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:IV" & bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy wbMain.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & lBeginRow)
        '** in above line i work directly with sheet

        With wbMain.Worksheets(1) 'to work with ThisWorkbook, Sheet 1 (change sheet index number as needed

            Dim lEndRow As Long
            lEndRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row '** get last copied row

            Dim lNextColumn As Long
            lNextColumn = .Range("A" & lBeginRow).End(xlToRight).Column + 1 '** get next column after data paste (asssume contigous columns of data)

            '** place file name in newly pasted range
            .Range(.Cells(lBeginRow, lNextColumn), .Cells(lEndRow, lNextColumn)).Value = bookList.Name

            lBeginRow = lEndRow + 1 '** reset next begin row before new paste

        End With

        bookList.Close

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I currently having error "Runtime Error 424". I noticed that this error occurs file per file.

Comment: Im currently new in VBA. when I run the code you provided, it will open the first file in the path an throw that error. "Runtime Error 424: Object Required"

Comment: when you hit debug after the error appears, which line is highlighted yellow? I also made few edits which may (or may not) help.

Comment: erro came here
 bookList.Sheets(1).Range("A2:IV" & bookList.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy bookList.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: did you try my edited code. perhaps the first sheet in the opened workbook is not a `worksheet`

Comment: I don't think you copied my code correctly. the error line you posted as bookList in the copy command and the *destination* argument. change destination argument to `wb`

Comment: Here's the updated line 
bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:IV" & bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & lBeginRow)

Im still getting the same error. Also, will this code merge the active sheet once you opened the file?

Comment: very sorry, It was a simple overlook. I dimensioned the variable as `wbMain`, then used `wb`. Please see edited answer again.

Comment: Hi Scott, I wasn't able get this working. New error found on this line Applicantion-defined or object-defined error.
".Range(.Cells(lBeginRow, lNextColumn), .Cells(lEndRow, lNextColumn)).Value = bookList.Name"

Comment: what are the values of `lBeginRow, lEndRow and lNextColumn` when the error occurs?

Comment: lBeginRow=1, lNextColumn=257, lEndRow = 1 here

Comment: is there just 1 row of data in the first workbook that is copied over?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding this Scott, the original code I've posted here works fine :)

Comment: its hard for me to test without data, but if you step-through it line-by-line with your actual data, you can probably figure out why the error is occurring.

Comment: I just have a data from column A to BL. First row as the header part...on my other post, im trying to add the filename for each file then save for one script. then the other script is for merging all files into one excel file. Will this be fine?