# How to increment cell based on the number of rows using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Let's say I have 2 files:

```
FILE1.xls
FILE2.xls
```

FILE1.xls contains:

```
AAA
BBB
```

FILE2.xls contains:

```
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

I currently have this code:

```
  Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileName1 As String

Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & myFile)

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      FileName = wb.Name
      FileName1 = Replace(FileName, ".xls", "")
      Range("B1:B2").Value = FileName1
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\guintop\Desktop\paul\MERGE")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next



ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If I run this code, it will:

- get the filename of the files present in the selected directory,
- insert the file name (without extension) the indicated cell for each file
- last part of the code will merge all files into one excel file.

and will have an output like this for final output file

```
AAA FILE1   
BBB FILE1
XXX FILE2
YYY FILE2
ZZZ        -> BLANK
```

As you noticed, the last part of ZZZ will be blank since I assigned the file name on the specific cell.
How can I adjust this code to automatically fill-out the cell B1-B3? or B1-B5 if I have 5 rows of data in cell A?

Comment: It would be something like range("a" & startrow).resize(1,rowcount).value=workbook name as you do the merge

Comment: although worded differently, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996476/how-to-add-column-in-final-excel-file-from-merged-excel-files) asked yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the last row with a value.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then use the value instead of hard coding the row.

```
Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value = FileName1
```